# Deploying angular app to Heroku using correct environments file

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment

I am working on an Angular4 app using the Angular CLI.
I have environments files (environments.prod.ts and environments.dev.ts).
I want to create two different apps on Heroku that each is using a different environments file, but both are deploying from the same git repo.

My app is delivered by a NodeJS server and running this script in package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install && cd ng-client && npm install && ng build",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

my Heroku `procfile` looks like that:

```
web:npm start
```

I know that eventually I need to run `ng build --prod` instead of `ng build`.

I was reading about environment variables I can pass to heroku environment. But how do I complete the entire cycle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own bash script and define that logic using the environment variables you set for your app on Heroku. The env variables can be set programmatically or on your app’s settings tab on the Dashboard. You can find more info about Heroku env vars [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

1. Configure the env variable on each of your environments on Heroku, if you are using Node.js, you can use the `NODE_ENV` var. For example, the Development app will be set as `NODE_ENV=development` and the Production app as `NODE_ENV=production`.
2. Create a bash script file on the root of your project, for example: `build.sh`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   echo "Building Angular app for $NODE_ENV"

   build_dev='ng build'
   if [ $NODE_ENV = "development" ]; then
    echo "running $build_dev ..."
    eval "$build_dev"
   fi

   build_prod='ng build --prod'
   if [ $NODE_ENV = "production" ]; then
    echo "running $build_prod ..."
    eval "$build_prod"
   fi
   ```
3. Run your bash script on the `heroku-postbuild` hook:

   ```
   ...
   "heroku-postbuild": "bash build.sh",
   ...
   ```

You can modify the `build.sh` according to your needs.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this the whole day, thanks a lot <3