# How do I use environment variables in heroku for my angular app?

Tags: angular, heroku

I am trying to set up environment variables (or, Config Vars in the Heroku world) such as production=true for my angular app in heroku.  But, I can't figure out how to set the `postinstall` and `build` scripts to use them. Putting this in my packahge.json file:

```
"postinstall": "ng build --aot --configuration=${ENV}"
```

just results in Heroku running this command:

```
> ng build --aot --configuration=${ENV}
```

If I can't change the build configuration, I can't take advantage of angular's file replacement in order to set things like my firebase api key.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@abhishek.garg_53728/change-environment-at-runtime-in-angular-with-heroku-39478c3dfcd0) which seemed to indicate that i could access the config vars in the package.json file, but it's not working.

I've also tried using just process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY in my environment.ts file and bypassing file replacements altogether, and while the app successfully builds in heroku, I see this in the console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I'm not sure what the best way to handle this is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by doing this:

1. Setting a Config Var `ENV` to be `production` or `staging`
2. Creating a post-install.js file:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

let command;

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    command = exec('ng build --aot --configuration=production');
} else if (process.env.ENV === 'staging') {
    command = exec('ng build --aot --configuration=staging');
}

if (command != undefined) {
    command.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    command.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(data);
    });

    command.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
} else {
    console.error('process.env.ENV: ' + process.env.ENV);
}
```

3. I then modified my `package.json`'s `postinstall` script to run that file

```
"postinstall": "node post-install.js"
```

So, when Heroku runs the postinstall script, it will build the appropriate version (and replace the correct environment file(s)).

Comment: I think you don't need this. After you've created the environment variable ENV in Heroku, you can just do: `ng build --aot --configuration=${ENV}`

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a pre-build.js file in your project directory:
   this code build a environment.prod.ts with variable from heroku variables

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var str = `
   export const environment = {
       production: true,
       my_key: '${process.env.MY_KEY}',
       env: '${process.env.ENV}'
   };
   `;
   fs.writeFile("./src/environments/environment.prod.ts", str, function(err) {
      if(err) {
         return console.log(err);
      }
       console.log("The file was saved!");
   });
   ```
2. Add **heroku-prebuild** action in pachage,json:

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "start": "node app.js",
       "heroku-prebuild": "node pre-build.js",
       "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
   }
   ```
3. Use them as standard Angular environment variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Heroku Dashboard to set enviroment variable like in this [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

Setting enviroment variable like this allow you to dynamic control your enviroment variable

So in Node.js, use `process.env.something` to access environment variables

Comment: I already set the environment variables in the dashboard, and I already tried using process.env, but received the error in my question.

Comment: Faced in the same problem. I would like to know why this don't works.

Comment: @FernandoKosh It doesn't work because process.env is only available in NodeJs (server technology). Angular runs in the browser, so it cannot see process.env stuff. There are many ways to solve this; the default is to use Angular's own environments folder, which the ng build command will read. So you can put process.env in those files and the build command, when running, will read them (since that command is run in the context of Node.Js). See the official Angular docs about this. https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: @FernandoKosh Also read this: https://ferie.medium.com/how-to-pass-environment-variables-at-building-time-in-an-angular-application-using-env-files-4ae1a80383c

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own bash script and define that logic using the environment variables you set for your app on Heroku.

See the first answer: [Deploying angular app to Heroku using correct environments file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547678/deploying-angular-app-to-heroku-using-correct-environments-file)

Answer (score -1):

I tried in many ways to build on Heroku side properly. 
Then I decided that is not a good idea for me.

Now, I **build it locally** then push to Heroku (or git).

For using ENV var on Heroku side, I **use PHP** to get env and pass to the app index.

In this example, I'm getting api_url:

**in INDEX.HTML**

```
<script>

    let apiFromEnv = '<?php echo getenv("API_URL")?>'
    if (apiFromEnv.indexOf('.com') > 0) {
        document.apiURL = apiFromEnv
    } else {
        document.apiURL = null
    }

</script>
```

**when you use in typescript:**

```
let apiURL = environment.API_URL;
if (document['apiURL']) {
  apiURL = document['apiURL'];
}
```

---

*After this line, I give an example to switch your node app to php*

Switching your app buildpack to php, use **composer.json**

You have to change index.html name to index.php after heroku install; this is **composer.json** file (put it root dir of the project nearby Procfile) it includes php for changing Heroku buildback.

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "mv dist/index.html dist/index.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

I use **.htaccess** to redirection rules and directory index for server:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php

</IfModule>
```

The last thing, don't forget to add .htaccess to angular.json assets copy rule:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      .....,
      "options": {
        ....
        "assets": [
          .....,
          "src/.htaccess"
        ],
......
```